# How to access Oracle Java resources to import for Java source

Tags: java, oracle, jar, jvm

Due to some restrictions at my place of employment and lots of red tape, I am currently trying to access a JAR I've uploaded as a Java Resource in Oracle in order to call methods in my own Java source that runs out of the DB JVM.

I've uploaded the JAR and I can see the resource, the DB object is named "Trireme". My Java source is attempting to import this resource traditionally

```
CREATE OR REPLACE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED "Test" AS
// select * from user_errors;

package x.x.x.node;
import io.apigee.trireme.core.NodeEnvironment;
import io.apigee.trireme.core.NodeScript;
...
NodeEnvironment env = new NodeEnvironment();
NodeScript script = env.createScript("my-test-script.js",
                               new File("my-test-script.js"), null);
....
```

But it is unable to do so. Is this even possible? Is there a different way to use the classes within the resource, and if so, how is it done? I'm unable to find a good example

EDIT:
To add to this, I've added noticed that if I comment out the code in the class and I do 
import io.apigee.trireme.core.*
 and I comment out the lines in the code, it does not fail. Not referencing a specific class lets it compile, but either way, I still get the missing symbol once new NodeEnvironment is called, or NodeEnvironment is mentioned in the import instead of *

Comment: What exact error do you get?

Comment: When I compile the Java Source object, I just get errors about not being able to find the resource like this

`0/0         symbol:   class NodeEnvironment
0/0         location: package io.apigee.trireme.core
0/0       JavaClassName:6: error: cannot find symbol
0/0       import io.apigee.trireme.core.NodeScript;`

Comment: Seems like the classes are either not loaded inside the database, or you do not have permissions to use them. Can you see those classes in `user_objects`?

Comment: That's kind of what I'm trying to get at; I've loaded the JAR as a resource instead of loading individually as classes (I can't use loadjava, I have to load classes from blobs and would have to do them individually for 5k classes, so in this case I used a resource object).

When I run select * from user_objects WHERE object_type = 'JAVA RESOURCE', I see my Trireme object.

If I were to have them as JAVA CLASS objects, I would be able to access them in the way above, I have other smaller packages referenced in that way

Comment: I feel like I need to reference it in a different way (I also tried including the obj name, import Trireme.io.apigee.trireme.core.NodeEnvironment;) if it is possible, but can't figure out how